# Should I use template files or just use conditional tags in index.php?

Tags: theme-development, templates, conditional-tags

## With Template Files

I am building a theme that has very few differences between templates. Right now I have it set up more or less like this:

- **`singular.php`** - Single pages/posts; full post content, comments
- **`home.php`** - The blog page; full post content, no comments
- **`index.php`** - Everything else; post excerpts

## With Conditional Tags

Looking at this setup, I realized that I could do something like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-column">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( is_singular() ) :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'full' );
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    elseif ( is_home() ) :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'full' );
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'excerpt' );
    endif;

endwhile; else : echo "Nothing here."; endif; ?>

</div> <!-- #main-column -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
?>
```

I like this method for the same reason I like template parts - code that would have been repeated is now in only one place. If I decide to change the overall structure of the page, I don't have to worry about editing multiple files.

## Is there an advantage/disadvantage to only using `index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a theme only needs 3 core files to be recognized as a proper theme. These files are:

- `index.php`
- `styles.css`
- `functions.php`

If you have these 3 files in your theme's folder, you are good to go. The point of having multiple template files is to open a way for developers and users to customize their content output. You don't have to do this, but I strongly suggest that you add specific template files at least for the following:

- `404.php`
- `search.php`
- `single.php`
- `archive.php`
- `comments.php`
- `page.php`

You never know what happens in the future. You might use a hundred conditionals in your `index.php` file, and then need a `single.php` tomorrow. Better to be prepared in the first place.

Comment: But as soon as `single.php` is added, it would override `index.php`, even in a child theme. `index.php` could even be used as a starting point if necessary, cutting out anything not required for `single.php`. Isn't it simpler to add a more specific template once it is needed than to maintain several template files that differ only slightly?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's totally optional. It depends how sophisticated your theme is, and what plans you have for it in the future.